# how to locate #username within shadow using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom

[please find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KwKl.png)I am trying to automate process of login and for this I am using selenium in python. But having a problem while getting element by id. I am stuck in this any help will be appreciated thanks